# Can I pause the running encryption of BitLocker?

Tags: windows, security, encryption, bitlocker

I have a 3 TB external hard drive that I want to encrypt with BitLocker. I have chosen a strong password as my unlock method. TPM is not used.

Can I pause BitLocker's ongoing encryption so I can temporarily unplug the external hard drive? Will the encryption continue when I reconnect it?

Comment: While you can pause the encryption process, I don't believe the rest of your data, will even be accessible.  You will have to specifically resume the process, it won't continue, automatically when the drive is reconnected.

Comment: There are many questions asked about being unable to open a BitLocker-protected disk. Interrupting the process seems to add an additional chance for corruption. Do you have backup of the disk if this fails??

Comment: Oh, I just recently read that interrupting the process safely using the "Pause" button is okay. I can't find the source anymore, though, but I'm pretty sure it was documented at the official Microsoft docs. I don't have a backup, but the stuff on the drive aren't that important.

Answer (score 2):

While the computer is busy encrypting the drive, you can temporarily pause the
Encryption.
Open an Administrative command prompt and issue the following command:

```
manage-bde -pause X:
```

where X: is the drive-letter being Encrypted.

You can resume the Encryption process with the following command:

```
manage-bde -resume X:
```

This can be done for both Encryption and Decryption.

See Microsoft documentation at
[manage-bde: pause](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/manage-bde-pause).

Comment: The BitLocker encryption dialog offers me a "Pause" button. Is that the same as `manage-bde -pause X:` ?

Comment: I would guess so.